Nest can't resolve dependencies when running tests
I want to create a unit test for my NestJS service, which is a database repository.
I have an error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RescuerFunctionRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument "RescuerFunctionRepository" at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context..
The code:
describe('RescuerFunctionRepository', () => {
  let repository: RescuerFunctionRepository

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [RescuerFunctionRepository],
    }).compile()

    repository = module.get<RescuerFunctionRepository>(RescuerFunctionRepository)
  })

    it('should be defined', () => {
      expect(repository).toBeDefined()
    })
})

It happens also when I add into Test.createTestingModule() an import statement with my module when I have registered SequelizeModule.
The structure of modules:

AppModule imports CommonModule.
CommonModule imports and exports DatabaseModule.
The DatabaseModule imports SequelizeModule and registers it using forRootAsync. All of the repositories are registered as providers and are exported.

How can I resolve this error?
EDIT: RescuerFunctionRepository code:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize'
import { CreationAttributes, Transaction, WhereOptions } from 'sequelize'
import { RescuerFunction } from '../../models/rescuer-function.model'

@Injectable()
export class RescuerFunctionRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(RescuerFunction)
    private userModel: typeof RescuerFunction
  ) {}

  find(where: WhereOptions<RescuerFunction>, trans?: Transaction): Promise<RescuerFunction | null> {
    return this.userModel.findOne({
      where: where,
      transaction: trans,
    })
  }

  insert(attributes: CreationAttributes<RescuerFunction>, trans?: Transaction): Promise<RescuerFunction> {
    return this.userModel.create(attributes, {
      transaction: trans,
    })
  }
}


we can only say that your testing module didn't have all the dependencies defined in the RescuerFunctionRepository provider.

@MicaelLevi I added the "RescuerFunctionRepository" code as an edit to the post. It only uses the SequelizeModule which is imported into my DatabaseModule. This error is displayed
regardless of whether it imports the DatabaseModule into createTestingModule() or not

I know what was wrong.
To the DatabaseModule to exports, I added SequelizeModule (before this wasn't exported). Added DatabaseModule and ConfigModule (with appropriate path to the .env file) to imports in the test file.

Also provide other service which you are using in your service.ts file
